# How to start a service from XML?

Tags: android, xml, service, preferences

I'm having no luck getting a service to start from a preference screen, and can't find any examples online. This is what I'm doing:

The preference XML:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:title="Start Service">
    <intent
        android:action="com.test.app.myservice" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The manifest:

```
<service
    android:enabled="true"
    android:name=".myservice">
    <intent-filter>
        <action
            android:action="com.test.app.myservice" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

The error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(7912): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.test.app.myservice }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message shows what happens: You need to start an Activity and not a Service. Try to build a normal preference activity and handle the change of the setting there.

Comment: Good idea, I hadn't considered that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try implementing a [registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%28android.content.SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener%29) and hook it up to a checkbox or something. That way, you can start or stop a service programmatically. I think this is probably a more preferred way to handle this situation. If you need to show the current status of the service (whether to check or uncheck) take a look at binding a local service.

Comment: I already have a menu like you describe, with a checkbox and listener. The problem is that it's a 'calibrate' task, and so it doesn't make sense to have a checkbox. WarrenFaith's suggestion that I make a new Preference object sounds like the most elegant workaround.

Answer (score 0):

you can register a receiver for your intent and start service from receiver, this is for if you want to.start service from any check.box of your preference screen, or else you can use existing callback functions onPreference change listners to start service in preference activity..